# issue with setState(), does not submit the whole input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error

In the react form page, I would like to be able to automatically submit the userInput (without the button). The desired input comes from all 6 separate input fields joined together as one number.

to do that I try to call the onSubmit function when the last input field is not empty:

```
    change = e => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

    if (e.target.value.length === e.target.maxLength && e.target.id <= 5){
        this.refs[parseInt(e.target.id, 6) + 1].focus();
    } else if (this.state.sixth.value !== ""){
        this.onSubmit();
        }
    };
```

however, the input from the last field is ignored. For example, input was abcdef but the result gives abcde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a common misconception that setState is synchronous.. and often times it completes fast enough where it seems that way, however it is not.  If you want to ensure that you are taking the state you just set into consideration, you will want to complete your action within the callback from setState.  Consider this:

```
change = e => {
  const target = e.target
  this.setState({[target.name]: target.value}, () => {
    if (target.value.length === target.maxLength && target.id <= 5){
        this.refs[parseInt(target.id, 6) + 1].focus();
    } else if (this.state.sixth.value !== ""){
        this.onSubmit();
    };
  });
}
```

edited to reflect comments about e.target falling out of scope.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Save `e.target.value` in a variable or it won't be available to the callback

Comment: edited to reflect.  i was just trying to illustrate the callback - i didn't expect a copy paste.. then again- this is SO.